# Why is this reference to an element unrecognized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this jQuery to try to get the value from a Datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        $.ajax({
            var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
            var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();

            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
                .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate));
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            cache: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (returneddata) {
                $("body").html(returneddata);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
            }
        }); // ajax
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }); // button click
}); // ready
```

...but it throws the error "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*" on the assignment to _begdate.

Why? Here is the html declaring that Datepicker:

```
<input class="smalldatepicker" type="date" id="datepickerFrom" name="daterangefrom" value="2016-08-14">
```

Its id is "datepickerFrom" - so why is attempting to assig its value to the var _begdate failing?

Comment: You placed your variable definitions inside of the object declaration in your ajax parameters. This is what is causing your error.

Comment: As an aside, it is best when using razor calls to wrap them in `()` to ensure that the scope is retained in case of collisions in the engine. ->`@(Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "GRAMPS", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" }))`

Comment: I had them outside at first, but that caused the references to them inside the ajax callback to turn red - indicating that they were unrecognized. Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no Ajax callback in this code. You're trying to declare variables inside an object literal.

Comment: The ellipsis dots show that some code was elided for brevity. I'll add the whole shebang.

Comment: Moving the declarations outside of the ajax call (no callback you are correct Juhana) should fix the error message. I don't see why any problems would be created from that.

Comment: It should be `document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
            var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        $.ajax({`

Comment: @TravisJ: Make it an answer, and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the variable definitions inside an object that is being passed to the `$.ajax` call.

It should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();

        $.ajax({    
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
                .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate));
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            cache: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (returneddata) {
                $("body").html(returneddata);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
            }
        }); // ajax
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }); // button click
}); // ready
```